# How many objects will be created when using this for loop?

Tags: java, oop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

Object obj = new Object();

}
```

Will 3 objects be created or only one object which gets re-instantiated 3 times?
What happens under the hood?

Comment: Do you mean how many objects will be created or how many will be stored in memory after the loop has finished executing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three objects will be created, because `new Object()` will be called three times.

There's no such concept as an object being "re-instantiated".

Now the same stack space may well be used to store the reference returned from the constructor, so you could argue that in some ways there's only one *variable*<sup>1</sup>, which is reinitialized on each iteration of the loop... but variables and objects are very different, and it's important that you separate the two concepts in your mind.

---

<sup>1</sup> In other ways there really are three separate variables, so please don't take this too far.

Comment: With escape analysis, you might find no objects are created because they don't do anything and are not used. I believe JRockit's optimisation can eliminate this code.

Comment: What happens to the object in memory referred to by `obj` at the start of the second iteration of the loop, once the second assignment happens? Is it collected after the execution of all iterations of the loop has finished or at the end of the second iteration? Or end of the method? Does it matter?

Comment: @StuperUser: Do you mean the object itself? It becomes *eligible* for garbage collection immediately, but it could be collected either immediately or much later... there are no guarantees.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Agreed - although I was trying to keep it at a *relatively* straightforward level. (Even without that optimization, the reference could end up in a register instead of on the stack etc, too.) It's always tricky knowing how much detail to go into :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't "reinstantiate" an object.  Every time you invoke the `new` keyword a new object will be created, so 3 will be created.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you use the "new" keyword, you will get a new Object. Since the reference is in local scope, the object will go out of scope after the loop condition and be a candidate for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating three different object on the heap memory, but after the loop, you'll can access only at the last object that you had created.

Edit: for "you can" I mean that **through that pointer** you can access only at last object.

Comment: Actually, given the scope of the declared variable, he can't access any of the objects after the loop is done. I guess you could say zero objects were created!

Comment: Oh yes you're totally right but I mean, in a different situation where the scope was "right", he can access only at the "last" object created

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the word `new` is used a new Object is created, so you are creating 3 objects. Although given the scope of the declared variable you cannot use any of the objects once the loop is finished.